# How to grab dx dy svg attribute in css

Tags: css, svg

Can anyone recommend me a best practice method of grabbing dx dy svg attribute in css. If this is not possible how do I do it in JS.

Comment: Please share the code where you have tried doing this and mention the problem you are facing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Through js, I would suggest the dom node [getAttribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattributenode.asp) method:

```js
var text = document.querySelector('text')

var dx = text.getAttribute('dx')

console.log('dx is', dx)
```

```html
<svg> 
  <text dx="20%" x="10%" y="50%">SVG</text>
</svg>
```